# arduino code ESP32 displays crypto prices - rounding decimals depeding on the price

Tags: arduino, decimal, esp32, cryptocurrency, e-ink

I'm playing with an ESP32 connected to an E-Paper display. I'm using a code already developed.
The code displays the current price for some cryptos I have selected and other info coming from other portions of the code.
For this part of the code, I would like to round the price displayed depending on the value of the crypto: if a crypto has a value of less than 1 I want it rounded to 6 decimals, between 1 and 10 I want it rounded to 4 decimals and above 100 only two decimals.
The portion of the code that displays the price is the following, I don't know what is the best solution to handle this.

```
*/
#ifndef BOARD_HAS_PSRAM
#error "Please enable PSRAM !!!"
#endif


#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <WifiClientSecure.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include "cryptos.h"
#include "coingecko-api.h"
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <esp_task_wdt.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "epd_driver.h"
#include "firasans.h"
#include "opensans8b.h"
#include "opensans10b.h"
#include "esp_adc_cal.h"
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>


#define BATT_PIN            36
#define SD_MISO             12
#define SD_MOSI             13
#define SD_SCLK             14
#define SD_CS               15

int cursor_x ;
int cursor_y ;

uint8_t *framebuffer;
int vref = 1100;

// ----------------------------
// Configurations - Update these
// ----------------------------

const char *ssid = "xxxxx";
const char *password = "xxxxx";


// ----------------------------
// ----------------------------


void setup()
{
  char buf[128];

  Serial.begin(115200);


  connectToWifi();

  // Correct the ADC reference voltage
  esp_adc_cal_characteristics_t adc_chars;
  esp_adc_cal_value_t val_type = esp_adc_cal_characterize(ADC_UNIT_1, ADC_ATTEN_DB_11, ADC_WIDTH_BIT_12, 1100, &adc_chars);
  if (val_type == ESP_ADC_CAL_VAL_EFUSE_VREF) {
    Serial.printf("eFuse Vref:%u mV", adc_chars.vref);
    vref = adc_chars.vref;
  }

  epd_init();

  framebuffer = (uint8_t *)ps_calloc(sizeof(uint8_t), EPD_WIDTH * EPD_HEIGHT / 2);
  if (!framebuffer) {
    Serial.println("alloc memory failed !!!");
    while (1);
  }
  memset(framebuffer, 0xFF, EPD_WIDTH * EPD_HEIGHT / 2);

  epd_poweron();
  epd_clear();

  epd_poweroff();

  epd_poweron();


}

void loop()
{
  downloadBaseData("eur");
  delay(1000);
  downloadBtcAndEthPrice();
  title();
  for (int i = 0; i < cryptosCount; i++)
  {
    cursor_y = (20 * (i + 4));
    renderCryptoCard(cryptos[i]);
  }
  delay(300000);
}

void title()
{

  cursor_x = 20;
  cursor_y = 40;
  char *sym = "Symbol";
  writeln((GFXfont *)&OpenSans10B, sym, &cursor_x, &cursor_y, NULL);

  cursor_x = 150;
  cursor_y = 40;
  char *prc = "Price";
  writeln((GFXfont *)&OpenSans10B, prc, &cursor_x, &cursor_y, NULL);

  cursor_x = 330;
  cursor_y = 40;
  char *da = "Day(%)";
  writeln((GFXfont *)&OpenSans10B, da, &cursor_x, &cursor_y, NULL);

  cursor_x = 430;
  cursor_y = 40;
  char *we = "Week(%)";
  writeln((GFXfont *)&OpenSans10B, we, &cursor_x, &cursor_y, NULL);


}

void renderCryptoCard(Crypto crypto)
{

  Serial.print("Crypto Name  - "); Serial.println(crypto.symbol);

  cursor_x = 35;

  char *string1 = &crypto.symbol[0];

  writeln((GFXfont *)&OpenSans10B, string1, &cursor_x, &cursor_y, NULL);

  cursor_x = 150;

  String Str = String (crypto.price.eur, 6);
  char* string2 = &Str[0];

  Serial.print("price eur - "); Serial.println(Str);

  Rect_t area = {
    .x = cursor_x,
    .y = cursor_y - 15,
    .width = 160,
    .height = 18,
  };

  epd_clear_area(area);

  writeln((GFXfont *)&OpenSans10B, string2, &cursor_x, &cursor_y, NULL);

  Serial.print("Day change - "); Serial.println(formatPercentageChange(crypto.dayChange));

  cursor_x = 330;

  Rect_t area1 = {
    .x = cursor_x,
    .y = cursor_y - 15,
    .width = 100,
    .height = 18,
  };

  epd_clear_area(area1);
  Str = (String)(crypto.dayChange);
  char* string3 = &Str[0];

  writeln((GFXfont *)&OpenSans10B, string3, &cursor_x, &cursor_y, NULL);


  Serial.print("Week change - "); Serial.println(formatPercentageChange(crypto.weekChange));

  cursor_x = 430;

  Rect_t area2 = {
    .x = cursor_x,
    .y = cursor_y - 15,
    .width = 100,
    .height = 18,
  };

  epd_clear_area(area2);

  Str = (String)(crypto.weekChange);
  char* string4 = &Str[0];

  writeln((GFXfont *)&OpenSans10B, string4, &cursor_x, &cursor_y, NULL);

}


void connectToWifi()
{
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  String dots[3] = {".", "..", "..."};
  int numberOfDots = 1;

  //tft.setTextColor(//tft_WHITE, //tft_BLACK);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    //tft.drawCentreString("Connecting to WiFi " + dots[numberOfDots - 1], 120, 120, 2);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi");
    if (numberOfDots == 3)
    {
      numberOfDots = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      numberOfDots++;
    }

    delay(300);
    //tft.fillScreen(//tft_BLACK);
  }

  Serial.println("Connected!!!_______________");

}




String formatPercentageChange(double change)
{


  double absChange = change;

  if (change < 0)
  {
    absChange = -change;
  }

  if (absChange > 100) {
    return String(absChange, 0) + "%";
  } else if (absChange >= 10) {
    return String(absChange, 1) + "%";
  } else {
    return String(absChange) + "%";
  }
}
```

'''

At first I thought to insert an if-else-else based on the price of the crypto, that changes the line only

```
   String Str = String (crypto.price.eur, 6) ;
```

but I don't know much about programming and despite several attempts I always get an error.
I'm sorry to ask such a stupid question, but I have just started :)

--
Marco

Comment: Hi Marco, welcome to SO. This is a very elementary task and I suggest it's a bit early in your programmer's career to ask SO for advice. Keep reading the C or C++ tutorials, you'll arrive at a solution on your own. Also, keep in mind that it's more useful to post the code that you've written - even if it doesn't work.

Comment: Hello! I followed the guidelines and posted only the portion related with the issue. I have no problem to share the entire code of course (I edited the main post). I know it is an easy task, and I thought it would have been easy to get an answer. Unfortunately I'm not a programmer and I wanted just to adjust it to my needs something already developed...  I have some many ideas I want to implement but it is not easy to start from scratch programming when during your life you have done no more than some excel formulas :)

Comment: What for 10 < value <= 100?

Comment: sorry @Armali , my mistake: below 1, 6 decimals; between 1 and 10,4 decimals and above 10, 6 decimals. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're right about the only line to be changed. Even simpler than *an if-else-else* is the conditional operator:

```
   double f = crypto.price.eur;    // just for brevity
   String Str = String(f, f<1 ? 6 : f<=10 ? 4 : 6);
```

By the way, you presumably erred when saying *below 1, 6 decimals; between 1 and 10,4 decimals and above 10, 6 decimals*, but you can easily adapt the above to the actual requirement.

Comment: outstanding... many thanks!